# Error when installing mod_wsgi

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

When installing mod_wsgi I get stuck after doing ./config

Apparently I am missing the apxs2

Here is the result:

checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
checking Apache version... 2.2.22
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

What I am not sure of now is how I get apxs2 working and installed. Any solution anyone? This is so that I can later on install Django and finally get a Python/Django environment up and running on my VPS.

Answer (score 2):

> checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
>    ...
>   config.status: creating Makefile

It succeeded. Go on to the next step.

Comment: Yeah but problem seems to be this: checking for apxs2... no

Comment: You have failed to define how that is a problem.

Comment: I assumed apxs2 would be required for the installation. Since it says no, I assumed that was a bad thing and required.

Answer (score 0):

You have Apache 2.2 core package installed, but possibly have the devel package for Apache 1.3 instead of that for 2.2 installed. This isn't certain though, as for some Apache distributions, such as when compiled from source code, 'apxs' is still called 'apxs'. It is only certain Linux distros that have changed the name of 'apxs' in Apache 2.2 distros to be 'apxs2'. This is why the mod_wsgi configure script checks for 'apxs2' as well as 'apxs'.

So, do the actual make and see if that fails before assuming you have the wrong apxs.